# Why doesn't Toad slime Storm in X1?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, toads-spit, x-men-2000

During the first half of the Liberty Island fight scene (Cyclops, Storm, Jean Grey & Wolverine vs Toad & Mystique), Wolverine is separated from the group by Mystique and Toad attacks the others by locking Cyclops in a display case, tossing Storm onto an overhead balcony, and spitting suffocating slime on Jean.

However, after seeing Storm watching him and Jean, he leaps to the balcony and smiles at her before kicking her all over the place, finally locking her in an empty elevator shaft. Why? If he had used the slime he had used on Jean Grey, wouldn't she have been just as helpless?

After all, he could easily prevent any of the other X-Men reaching her before she ran out of air. Not to mention, she could easily fall into the open elevator shaft or over the edge of the balcony and break her neck. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Added paragraph breaks - the original was a little hard to read.

Comment: toad questions man...

Answer (score 4):

Like any other biological liquid, he would have to build it up again before he could use it.

Comment: Source on this, or examples of needing to recharge/build up? I've never seen this mentioned in any of the versions of him that have the slime ability.

Comment: It's just too easy sometimes.

Comment: @phantom42 common logic would state that if a human wants to spit a loogie out, he/she has to build that puppy up and then unleash the load. Toad is a mutant and his spit are super sticky but he doesnt have a quantum pocket in his mouth where he has an endless supply of spit hidden. He would have to build the charge in some way.

Comment: @Cherubel Are we seriously going to assume that "common logic" necessarily applies to comic books and comic book characters?

Comment: @phantom42 well we can assume thai it is done by applying magic pixie dust for all i care. Comic books are made by mortal men that are at least bound to some kinds of scientific constraints (under their creative process). So it is plausible to think that if you ask the dude that "invented" Toad how does his spit Work that the answer wound prob be wel same as our spit but on a hyper acelerated level or some such mumbo jumbo.

Answer (score 1):

Well simple the Toad needed a way to loosen Jean's grip so what better way than to surprise spew a gross slime in her face. It would have been a bit overdone if he slimed Storm too, plus that makes the film a bit anti-female with two rather strong characters downed by a simple little Toad slime in their faces. Storm was stronger in the movie than Jean, so it was believable to see Jean Grey taken out.